# Convert Base16 to Base10

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pi, decimal-expansion

I am currently trying to use Y-Cruncher to calculate Pi.

Upon calculating 100 digits of Pi, I get this result:
`3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679`

However, Y-Cruncher also calculates the hex value of pi:
`3.243f6a8885a308d313198a2e03707344a4093822299f31d0082efa98ec4e6c89452821e638d01377be54`

After putting the hex value through an online converter, the hex value does not match the decimal value. I am certain that the hex value of pi isn't wrong, because when checking the official value of pi in hex, (https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start=0&numberOfDigits=85&radix=16), it matches exactly. How does one convert the hex value of pi to the decimal value of pi?

Comment: How does the resulting decimal value differ from what it should be? Seems OK to me.

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=3.243f6a8885a308d313198a2e03707344a4093822299f31d0082efa98ec4e6c89452821e638d01377be54+from+base+16+to+base+10) says this converts correctly as far as I checked

Comment: If you use "[convert base](https://math.stackexchange.com/)" in the searchbox on this site,  you'll find plenty of detailed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic procedure:

Assume that $d_1, \cdots, d_n$ are the **known** base 16 digits, to the right of the decimal point.

Assume that $x_1, \cdots, x_r$ are the **to be determined** base 10 digits.

Note that since each prime factor of $(16)$ is also a prime factor of $(10)$, that $r$ **must be finite**.  That is, the expansion of the base 16 number with $n$ digits after the decimal point must be expressible by a finite number of base $10$ decimal digits.

More explicitly:

$(16)^n$ is a divisor of $\left[(10)^4\right]^n.$

Therefore, $r$ is bounded above by $(4n)$.

---

Let $$T_0 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d_i}{(16)^i}.$$

Find $x_1 \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}$ such that
$$\frac{x_1}{10} \leq T_0 < \frac{x_1 + 1}{10}.$$

Compute

$$T_1 = T_0 - \frac{x_1}{10}.$$

Then, continue the iterative process, which should only take a finite number of steps:

Find $x_k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}$ such that
$$\frac{x_k}{(10)^k} \leq T_{k-1} < \frac{x_1 + 1}{(10)^k}.$$

Compute

$$T_k = T_{k-1} - \frac{x_k}{(10)^k}.$$

After a finite number of steps, you will have computed $x_1, \cdots, x_r$ and $T_r$ will equal $0$.

Comment: How do we decide whether $\frac{x_1}{10} \leq T_0 < \frac{x_1 + 1}{10}$? Do we first work out the sum $T_0$ numerically using arbitrary-precision arithmetic? If this arithmetic was done in base ten then we already have the digits we want.

Comment: @DavidK Very good point.  My intention is that $T_0$ be computed exactly as a fraction whose denominator is $(10)^{(4n)}.$  So, what you are saying is absolutely true.  However, the point of my response was to stretch the OP's (i.e. original poster's) intuition to have a deeper understanding of the relationship between $d_1, \cdots, d_n$ and $x_1, \cdots, x_r$.

Comment: @DavidK Also, suppose (for example) that instead of converting the base 16 number to base 10 digits after the decimal point, it was desired to express the base 16 number to base 7 (for example) digits after the decimal point.  Other than the fact that the expression may be infinite, with a finite period, you would follow the same procedure.  The only reason that the *shortcut* exists when converting to base 10 is that base 10 is how we are **accustomed** to computing.

Comment: Using base-ten arithmetic to convert hexadecimal to base seven is almost like doubling the work (but only "almost", because our familiarity with base ten means most of us calculate much quicker in that base). Basically that's saying to convert hexadecimal to decimal, then convert decimal to base seven. Converting directly between two bases, to me, means doing the arithmetic in one of the bases. So there's no "shortcut" to convert to base ten; but there is a "long way around" (via base ten) to do conversions between other bases.

Comment: But I think we've gotten far off the topic of the question, which I think was asking for a practical algorithm that one can follow. You have a practical algorithm (if they mean to do this all by hand) on the first line. If they mean to have a computer do the work, I think a completely different approach is better.

Comment: @DavidK I agree.  I was going to respond by asking (for example) how one would convert $~\dfrac{1}{16}$ into a number with base 7 digits after the decimal point, but you are right.  This is too far off-topic to the original question.

Comment: @DavidK I intend on using a computer. What would be the suggested algorithm for this?

Comment: @stefano I know that Java (for example) has a **Big Integer** class that allows you to perform computations against integers well above (for example) $10^{(100)}.$  Presumably, any computer programming language that you choose (i.e. C, Python, ...) will have similar facilities.  As David K indicated, all that you need to do is express $T_0$ as a fraction whose numerator is an integer that is less than $(10)^{(4n)}$ and whose denominator is $10^{(4n)}.$

Comment: @stefano Re my last comment, it is **critical** that you perform **exact** computations, with the large integers.  Any attempt to involve (for example) floating point decimal numbers with **limited** precision will always leave open the possibility of rounding errors.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2661923, One more quick thing if you're here still. How do you handle the "." in the hex input?

Comment: @stefano $ab.cd$ in base 16 equals $$[a \times (16)^1] +  [b \times (16)^0] + [c \times (16)^{(-1)}] + [d \times (16)^{(-2)}].$$  Also, $$(16)^{-n} = \frac{1}{(16)^n} = \frac{M}{(10)^{(4n)}},$$ where $M$ is some non-negative integer.

Comment: Ah, this makes a lot of sense now. Thanks!